# Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2048, but received input with shape (32, 512)

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import datasets

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
def preprocess(images):
  images = images.astype('float32') / 255.0
  images = np.pad(images, ((0,0), (2,2), (2,2)), constant_values=0.0)
  images = np.expand_dims(images, -1)
  return images

x_train = preprocess(x_train)
x_test = preprocess(x_test)


#encoder
encoder_input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 1), name="encoder_input")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding="same")(encoder_input_layer)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding="same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding="same")(x)
shape_before_flatten = K.int_shape(x)[1:]
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)

encoder_output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

encoder = tf.keras.models.Model(encoder_input_layer, encoder_output_layer)
encoder.summary()

# Decoder
decoder_input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,), name="decoder_input")
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(np.prod(shape_before_flatten))(decoder_input_layer)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((shape_before_flatten))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding="same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding="same")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding="same")(x)

decoder_output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, activation='sigmoid', padding="same")(x)

decoder = tf.keras.models.Model(decoder_input_layer, decoder_output_layer)
decoder.summary()

model = tf.keras.models.Model(encoder_input_layer, decoder(encoder_output_layer))
model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    x_train, x_train,
    validation_data = (x_test, x_test),
    shuffle = True,
    epochs = 3
)
```

```
prediction = model.predict(x_test[34])
```

Model training is done without any error but I'm getting this error when i try to regenerate the image saying shape mismatch, How it is possible?, it must show the same error during training

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model_5' (type Functional).

```
Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2048, but received input with shape (32, 512)

Call arguments received by layer 'model_5' (type Functional):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 32, 1), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```